# JQTouch - load from external links with transition, html data

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

How use it?
I use

```
    [div class='content']
    [a href="test.html"]SecondPage[/a]
    [/div]
```

But when i click, loads a empty page
Can you give me some example? please

Answer (score 1):

Test.html must contain just div.

```
  <div id="jqt">
        <div id="home" class="edgetoedge">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <h1>Books</h1>          
            </div>
            <ul class="edgetoedge">             
                <li><a href="jsp/bookedit.jsp">Book Add</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

bookedit.jsp below

```
<div id="forms">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Forms</h1>
        <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
    </div>
    <form class="scroll">
        <ul class="edit rounded">
            <li>Author : <input type="text" name="author" value="">
            </li>
            <li>Title :<input type="text" name="title" value="">
            </li>
            <li>Available :<input type="checkbox" name="available" value="true">
            </li>

        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```